# How can I show/hide divs depending on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement, dropdown

I am just learning javascript and I could use some help. I have found a way to show #divA if one of the first two options are selected but how can I show #divB if the third option is selected? I don't want these divs to show unless the corresponding option is selected in the dropdown menu.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="showOptionsBelow(this)">
      <option></option>
      <option value="First option">First option</option>
      <option value="Second option">Second option</option>
      <option value="Third option">Third option</option>
</select>

<div id="divA" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="divB" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function showOptionsBelow(elem) {
    if (elem.value == "First Option" || elem.value == "Second Option") {
      document.getElementById("divA").style.display = "block";
    } else {document.getElementById("divA").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: So what's stopping you from adding `document.getElementById("divB").style.display = "block";` in the `else` part. and `document.getElementById("divB").style.display = "none";` if the condition is evaluated as `true`?

Comment: Just extend your if / then to include an else if branch that addresses the third option being selected.

Comment: And to add to Scott's comment, you can also use [swith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) to avoid ugly `if else if else if...` condition

Comment: @alonEitan I believe I have tried this but perhaps I made a mistake. Would you mind typing that out?

Comment: @JustinBrewer Sure - The `option` in the select is not the same as the `Option` the condition: `"option" != "Option"` (Note the capital O)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are passing the whole select element into the showOptionsBelow function. Try this:

```
console.log(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value)
```

Comment: Actually `elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value` is equivalent to `elem..value`, and this won't fix the real problem wich is the typo in the `if condition`. How does that do the trick?!

Answer (score 2):

Well you just  need to hide the second div when you show the first and show the second one when you hide the first, do the same with the second div:

```
  if (elem.value == "First option" || elem.value == "Second option") {
    document.getElementById("divA").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("divB").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("divB").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("divA").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**Note:**

Make sure you use the correct `"First option"` and `"Second option"` from the options values in your `if` condition, otherwise your condition will be always false and you will fall always in the `else` statement.

**Demo:**

```js
function showOptionsBelow(elem) {
  if (elem.value == "First option" || elem.value == "Second option") {
    document.getElementById("divA").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("divB").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("divB").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("divA").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" onchange="showOptionsBelow(this)">
      <option></option>
      <option value="First option">First option</option>
      <option value="Second option">Second option</option>
      <option value="Third option">Third option</option>
</select>

<div id="divA" style="display:none;">A</div>
<div id="divB" style="display:none;">B</div>
```

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you, yes I am wondering how does the other answer do the trick!!